# Duplicate entries appending from json object

Tags: php, jquery, json

i have searched from stackoverflow and implemented the following jquery code, which is to get the json object from php and append it as li tags, but its appending 3 instances of one value. 
**Sample code is:**

```
   var $childs = $('.childs');


            $.getJSON('common/db/fetchUniversity.php', function(data) {
            $(data).each(function() {
                var $element = $childs.clone().removeClass('childs').appendTo('#colleges');
                $element.attr('id', this.id+"u");
                $element.html("<a href='#' class='img'><strong><img alt='image' src='images/mit.jpg' style='height:40px; width:40px;' /></strong></a><div style='padding-right: 30px;'><h4 style='display:inline; margin:1px;'>"+this.name+"</h4><p style='display:inline;'>"+this.description+"</p></div><p style='margin:2px;'><a href='#' style='text-decoration: none;'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus' style='display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;'></span>Follow</a></p><ul class='actions'><li class='remove'><a href='javascript:RemoveMe('#"+this.id+"u')'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-closethick'>close</span></a></li></ul>");
                });
            });


            $.getJSON('common/db/fetchPeople.php', function(data1) {
                $(data1).each(function() {
                    var $element = $childs.clone().removeClass('childs').appendTo('#people');
                    $element.attr('id', this.id+"p");
                    $element.html("<a href='#' class='img'><strong><img alt='image' src='"+btoa(this.pic)+"' style='height:40px; width:40px;' /></strong></a><div style='padding-right: 30px;'><h4 style='display:inline; margin:1px;'>"+this.name+"</h4><p style='display:inline;'>"+this.job_desc+","+this.location+"</p></div><p style='margin:2px;'><a href='#' style='text-decoration: none;'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus' style='display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;'></span>Follow</a></p><ul class='actions'><li class='remove'><a href='javascript:RemoveMe('#"+this.id+"p')'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-closethick'>close</span></a></li></ul>");
                    });
                });


            $.getJSON('common/db/fetchGroups.php', function(data) {
                $(data2).each(function() {
                    var $element = $childs.clone().removeClass('childs').appendTo('#groups');
                    $element.attr('id', this.id+"g");
                    $element.html("<a href='#' class='img'><strong><img alt='image' src='images/groups/hbr.jpg' style='height:40px; width:40px;' /></strong></a><div style='padding-right: 30px;'><h4 style='display:inline; margin:1px;'>"+this.name+"</h4><p style='display:inline;'>"+this.job_desc+","+this.location+"</p></div><p style='margin:2px;'><a href='#' style='text-decoration: none;'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus' style='display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;'></span>Follow</a></p><ul class='actions'><li class='remove'><a href='javascript:RemoveMe('#"+this.id+"g')'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-closethick'>close</span></a></li></ul>");
                    });
                });
```

the above code is fetching 3 json objects, and appending it to li tags, but all the above are adding 3 instances of single value. li tags are inside of jquery accordion.

When i hit json php file, its returning correct, i guess jquery code is doing something wrong to me. Please let me know where i am going wrong.

**json object, when entered in browser:-**

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Stanford university","description":"One of the best university in the world"},{"id":2,"name":"Princeton University","description":"One of the best university in the world"},{"id":3,"name":"Yale University","description":"One of the best university in the world"},{"id":4,"name":"California University","description":"One of the best university in the world"},{"id":5,"name":"Yale University","description":"One of the best university in the world"},{"id":6,"name":"California University","description":"One of the best university in the world"},{"id":7,"name":"Princeton University","description":"One of the best university in the world"},{"id":8,"name":"Stanford university","description":"One of the best university in the world"},{"id":9,"name":"California University","description":"One of the best university in the world"},{"id":10,"name":"Princeton University","description":"One of the best university in the world"},{"id":11,"name":"Yale University","description":"One of the best university in the world"}]
```

the above id:1 values are appending 3 times, it is happening for all the values.

Comment: It's easier to take care about esacaping `\"` instead of using `'` ?

Comment: Try placing `console.log(data);` at the beginning of each callback (matching dataN to the callback). Let me know if you're getting the proper data objects in each callback.

Comment: @RainDiao $childs is variable which stores a css class, its value is ``{display:none;}`` sorry for not mentioning it..

Comment: are you sure it refers to only one elememt? would you mind to try `console.log($childs.length)`?

Comment: @roXon ya didnt thought it, i have modified it..

Comment: I mean, if any possibility, there are more that one elements with class `.childs` in your DOM.

Comment: @RainDiao yes bro your right, all three functions were using .childs class, so i was getting 3 instances of each value, as i was calling 3 times, now when i gave different class names, it was perfectly fetching... thanks. Please post it as answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there are more than one elements with class **childs** in your DOM.